# Vue props become optional when using Object.assign to merge multiple prop definitions in defineProps

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-props

I use a const `MODAL_OPTION_PROP` to define common props for modal as below:

```js
export const MODAL_OPTION_PROP = {
  modalOption: {
    type: Object as PropType<ModalOptionParams>,
    default: DEFAULT_MODAL_OPTION,
  },
};
```

And try to apply it in a modal component `defineProps`

```js
const props = defineProps(
  Object.assign({}, MODAL_OPTION_PROP, {
    currentItem: {
      type: Object as PropType<Item>,
      required: true,
    },
  })
);

const editingItem = ref<Item>(props.currentItem);
```

Then a `not assignable` warning occurs on `props.currentItem`:

```
(property) currentItem?: Item | undefined
Argument of type 'Item | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Item'.ts(2345)
```

It seems that `currentItem` becomes optional. Are there any ways to avoid this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using spread operator instead of Object.assign?

Comment: @Romalex Oh, spread operator works!! But why? I suppose they should work same ... BTW, you can provide an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can use spread operator instead of Object.assign.

```
const props = defineProps(
  {
    ...MODAL_OPTION_PROP,
    currentItem: {
      type: Object as PropType<Item>,
      required: true,
    },
  }
)
```

To be honest i'm not sure what's the difference, but i think it has something to do with defineProps being a macros rather than a function. It probably just can't parse complex expressions like Object.assign

Comment: I did a survey and found the reason why spread operation works. Object.assign and spread operator handle property's enumerability in different ways, and the "required" enumerability effects the prop is required or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much simpler:

```
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    modalOption?: ModalOptionParams;
    currentItem: Item;
  }>(),
  {
    modalOption: DEFAULT_MODAL_OPTION,
  }
);

const editingItem = ref(props.currentItem);
```

No need to use `Object.assign`

Comment: It works, but I prefer to define props type, default, requirement in the same object. On the other hand, It is not ideal to export `ModalOptionParams`, `DEFAULT_MODAL_OPTION` in all components which use modal props.

Comment: I would argue that it is better to export / import things where you provide / consume them. It is clearly apparent where what is used

Comment: I think it depends. In my use case, `ModalOptionParams` is a type definition, and it would be shown automatically in IDE when we use `props.modalOption`, to export it seems not necessary.